# What is the best way to handle URLs between test and production in Java/Jetty/Eclipse/GitHub

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

When I push my latest version of code from my laptop up on GitHub and pull it down into my production box I have to change the urls. This causes problems with eGit when I pull down the next update from development that I pushed up to GitHub.

I have several places where I have coded a url, either localhost in test or 73.189... for my production server. For example, I don't think I can do Cross-Origin Resource Sharing without specifying a url in the code. When I put it up on GitHub and pull it down into production I have to change the urls. This causes problems with eGit when I pull down the next version from development.

I would like some direction to where someone has handled varying the urls in java based on environment because I suspect if can be done or the git command sequence to blow away my production code (on my "production" eclipse/jetty system) and overlay it from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood correctly, but under Windows you could use the hosts file to redirect it. In your project you use the address that you configurate in hosts now.

```
127.0.0.1 yourSite.com
127.0.0.1 73.189
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the obvious solution is to make the URLs configurable (e.g. using a [properties file](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)), and program your app to use the configuration instead of hardcoding the URLs.

Another solution is to always use production URLs.  When testing the dev site, use a [host entry](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/) to point your browser at the development site.

But the best solution, if possible, is to use relative URLs only.

Comment: I think these are perhaps the best solutions. However, I am a code guy and want to keep it in the code until I can pay someone to manage property files for me. Excellent you included the host entry link. I knew that but had forgotten about it until I saw it. Most people should start there as it supports windows and linux (for the quick and dirty fix).

Answer (score 0):

`Sysstem#getEnv()` can give you the value of an environment variable. Best practice for cloud deployments tends to involve pulling runtime variable information from the environment, for example credentials and host information for databases, operation flags, and server URLs. You can put the local development values as defaults within the sources, for when the environment variables are not defined.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion for Sysstem#getEnv() is exactly what I needed. I searched on it and the Orcale java tutorial has an example which copied into my code with success! On Ubuntu System.getenv() returns all kinds of information including the system name which I will parse to select configuration I need. This worked for me:

```
import java.util.Map;
Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(env);
    }
```